# Approximation of $ \frac{n!}{(n-2x)!}(n-1)^{-2x} $

Tags: approximation, factorial

I would like to find an approximation when $ n \rightarrow\infty$ of $ \frac{n!}{(n-2x)!}(n-1)^{-2x} $. Using Stirling formula, I obtain $$e^{\frac{-4x^2+x}{n}}. $$  The result doesn't seem right!

Below is how I derive my approximation. I use mainly Stirling Approximation and $e^x =(1+\frac{x}{n})^n $.

$$\frac{n!}{(n-1)^{2 x} (n-2 x)!}\approx \frac{\left(\sqrt{2 \pi } n^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-n}\right) (n-1)^{-2 x}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } e^{2 x-n} (n-2 x)^{-2 f+n+\frac{1}{2}}}\approx \frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-2 x} n^{-2 x} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-2 x}}{(n-2 x)^{n-2 x+\frac{1}{2}}}\approx e^{-2 x} \left(\frac{n}{n-2 x}\right)^{n-2 x+\frac{1}{2}} \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^{-\frac{2 x}{n}}\approx e^{-2 x} \left(\frac{n}{n-2 x}\right)^{n-2 x+\frac{1}{2}} e^{\frac{2 x}{n}}\approx \left(\frac{n-2 x}{n}\right)^{-n+2 x-\frac{1}{2}} \left(\frac{n-2 x}{n}\right)^n e^{\frac{2 x}{n}}\approx \left(\frac{n-2 x}{n}\right)^{2 x-\frac{1}{2}} e^{\frac{2 x}{n}}\approx \left(\left(1-\frac{2 x}{n}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{2 x}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n}} e^{\frac{2 x}{n}}\approx \left(e^{-2 x}\right)^{\frac{2 x}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n}}=e^{\frac{x-4 x^2}{n}}$$

I would appreciate your input!

Comment: Thanks @O.L.; It is the old notation, I fixed it. It should be $x$.

Comment: It seems that both results are not fine. My calculation, based on Stirling approximation, gives $e^{x(3-2x)/n}$.

Comment: @O.L. I just added how I derived my approximation, can you please share how you reached your results?

Comment: I just plotted your expression and it seems to work as charm. I would appreciate to have the steps you went through so to discover my errors. Thanks.

Comment: First, replace $2x$ with $k$. $2x$ is just adding noise to your calculation, giving more room to make errors. Then simplify by changing the problem to estimating $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}n^{-k}$$ and then estimating $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{-k} \approx e^{k/n}$.

Comment: In the beginning of the 3rd line of your calculation, you replace $e^{-2x}$ by $(1-2x/n)^n$. This is true in the leading order, but not true in the next order. If you correct this, you will recover the right result.

Comment: Thanks @O.L. for your input. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the orders of approximation (just discovered them). Would you please be more explicit or refer me to some material that I can study? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the correct approximation is to use Stirling in the logarithmic form:
$$\ln n!=n(\ln n-1)+\frac12 \ln \left(2\pi n\right)+\frac{1}{12n}+O(n^{-3}),$$
which also implies
$$\ln\frac{n!}{(n-2x)!}=2x \ln n+\frac{x-2x^2}{n}+O(n^{-2}).$$
Now using that
$$\ln (n-1)^{-2x}=-2x\ln(n-1)=-2x\ln n+\frac{2x}{n}+O(n^{-2}),$$
we get
$$\ln\left[\frac{n!}{(n-2x)!}(n-1)^{-2x}\right]=\frac{3x-2x^2}{n}+O(n^{-2}).$$

Comment: How do you subtract $n(\ln n -1)-(n-2x)(\ln(n-2x)-1)$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews \begin{align}
& \quad n\ln n- (n-2x)\ln (n-2x)=\\
&=n\ln n- (n-2x) [\ln n+\ln \left(1-2x/n \right)]=\\
&=n\ln n- (n-2x) [\ln n -2x/n-2x^2/n^2+O(n^{-3})]=\\
&=2x\ln n+2x -\frac{2x^2}{n}+ O(n^{-2}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We will first approximate $$f(n,k)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}n^{-k} = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)$$

Actually, we will approximate the logarithm of this value.

$$\begin{align}\log f(n,k) &= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \log\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)\\&= -\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^j\\&=-\sum_j \frac{1}{jn^{j}}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} i^j
\end{align}$$

So $$\log f(n,k) = -\frac{k(k-1)}{2n} -\frac{k(k-1)(2k-1)}{12n^2} + O(n^{-3})$$

Also $$\log\left(\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{-k}\right) = k\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}+O(n^{-3})\right)=\frac{k}{n}+\frac{k}{2n^2} + O(n^{-3})$$

Adding,we get that $$\log\left(\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(n-1)^{-k}\right)=\frac{2k-k(k-1)}{2n}+O(n^{-2}) = \frac{3k-k^2}{2n}+O(n^{-2})$$
Putting $k=2x$ we get:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-2x)!}(n-1)^{-2x} = \exp\left(\frac{3x-2x^2}{n}+O(n^{-2})\right)$$